# Wicket: Control page flow

Tags: java, wicket

is there a way to control and interrupt the Page-flow in wicket?
Here is an example, what I want to do:

If have a application with 20 pages. Some of these pages are available via central navigation links. Other pages are only available via links in other pages. If someone clicks on a link or uses the browser back button, I want to call a method in my current page, befor accessing the new page. Ideally these method has the ability, to interrupt the page-flow an my application stays on the page, where the link was pressed. I don't want to do this with javascript. I believe, there are possibilities in wicket, but I don't know where. :-)

Regards
Jens

Answer (score 0):

You can easily control the flow page from Wicket, just add a link/button component.
For example:

In your HTML:

```
<a href="#" wicket:id="yourLink">Go somewhere</a>
```

Your associate java:

```
add(new Link<Void>("yourLink") {
  @Override
  public void onClick() {
    // Do whatever you need and decide the target page
    setResponsePage(YourDesiredPage.class);
  }
});
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem with the back-button.
I want to "catch" those interactions and do an generic handling for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for **IRequestCycleListener** 
http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/request/cycle/IRequestCycleListener.html

that you can set in your Wicket application, see http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/Application.html#getRequestCycleListeners%28%29